# I am having trouble initializing arrays with multiple methods.

Tags: java, arrays, methods, method-call

I'm having some difficulties figuring out exactly how tot initialize my arrays for a project. I have an array being created in one method and it being called and copied in another then called to another method to be printed and i can't seem to get it to work correctly.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Tention_ArrayProcessing{ 
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        int[] inputData = inputData();
        int[] array = new int[SIZE];
        for (int i =0; i < inputData.length; i++)
        array[i] = inputData[i];
        printArray();
        }

public static int[] inputData() throws IOException{
// gets file name   
        String data;
        Scanner filename = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a file name please. Include extension");
        data = filename.next();
        filename.close();
//Reads from file and places data in array
        int i = 0;
        File file = new File (data);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        final int SIZE = inputFile.nextInt;
        int[] inputData = new int[SIZE];
        while (inputFile.hasNext() && i < inputData.length){
        inputData[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
        i++;
        }
        System.out.println();
        inputFile.close();
        return inputData;
        }
public static void printArray(int[] array){
//calls inputData method for array then prints it.
        int c = 0;
        System.out.println("Printing Array:");
        for( int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        System.out.print(array[i] +" ");
        c++;
        if (c == 10){
        System.out.println();
        }
        }
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I have 3 errors im getting with this java:17: error: cannot find symbol                                 
                int[] array = new int[SIZE];                                                  java:20: error: method printArray in class Tention_Array
Processing cannot be applied to given types;
                printArray();                                        
  java:34: error: cannot find symbol
                final int SIZE = inputFile.nextInt;
                                          ^

Comment: dont initialize variables in your main method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

int[] array = new int[inputData.length];

printArray(array);

int SIZE = inputeFile.nextInt();